# C++ Builder XE2 - different executable name for debug and release version

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, executable, c++builder-xe2

Is it possible to have different executable name for debug and release version? The executable should be copied to the same output directory for example

C:\Projects\Hello world\bin

In this particular case I want to output two files:

C:\Projects\Hello world\bin\ **Hello world.exe**

and

C:\Projects\Hello world\bin\ **Hello worldD.exe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Post-Build** event to rename the executable after it has been compiled.  Different build configurations can have different events defined.

Comment: If you rename or move (not copy) the executable in Post-build, you can no longer press F9 to run/debug it because the IDE expects the original name :/ I wonder why you can no longer adjust the output executable name in XE as you could in BCB. And you can do it in most or all other environments... Looks like the command-line linker, ilink32, allows for that, but I don't know if it is possible to configure that in IDE/project settings. And it would most probably confuse the IDE anyway, just like move/rename.

Answer (score 1):

On my C++ Builder XE8 installation, there seems to be a cleaner way to do it, although it can't be set through the IDE.  And, as noted elsewhere, debugging still seems to be broken.

From the `CodeGear.Cpp.Targets` file on my installed copy, we have:

```
<!-- Output Directories and Filenames -->
<OutputName Condition="'$(OutputName)'==''">$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputName>
<FinalOutput Condition="'$(FinalOutput)'==''">$(FinalOutputDir)$(DllPrefix)$(OutputName)$(DllSuffix)$(OutputExt)$(DllVersion)</FinalOutput>
```

Therefore, it looks as though you can set the OutputName property yourself to change the output filename on a per-configuration basis.

For example, on a simple VCL Forms Application, I was able to set it for the Debug Win32 configuration like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
    <OutputName>testmyapp</OutputName>
    <snip>
```

Obviously, you'd want to duplicate this line in the appropriate `PropertyGroup` elements.  If this doesn't make sense, I recommend reading up on how MSBuild property groups and conditions work, since that is what Embarcadero's build system is based on.

**If this whole situation bothers you, I suggest voting for the feature request which I have created here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13108**